# Check if element in for each loop is empty

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am building a webcrawler right now. I've got this for each loop:

```
for(Element src : images) {
            System.out.println("Source " + src.attr("abs:src"));
        }
```

How do I make my program print out that there is no image if there is no element src in images?

Comment: you can use  exceptions for that...https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exceptions-in-java/

Comment: @SarbjyotSinghChahal Don't use exceptions for control flow.

Comment: simply check if ``images`` is empty by checking its ``size()``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that your `images` is a available `ArrayList<>`, you should do like this:

```
   if(images.size() > 0){
      for (Element src : images){
          if (src != null) {
             System.out.println("Source " + src.attr("abs:src"));
          }
      }
  } else {
      System.out.println("There are no elements in ArrayList<> images");
  }
```

First you check if there are elements in the ArrayList. If there are no Elements insite, print it out. if there are elements, you go through the foreach loop and check each elements if it is not null.

Comment: I don't think ``src`` itself might be null, rather ``src.attr("abs:src")`` might be ``null`` and has to be checked

Comment: But the question was, how to detect if the ArrayList has elements inside and if not, print it out.